# How to save new data to current excel file

Tags: excel, vba

It exist an excel file at my path: `E:\g1.xlsx`
I want to add value to this file.

but my function always create new file:

```
Function wirteToExcelFile(path, sheet)
Dim oApp_Excel As Excel.Application
Dim oBook As Excel.Workbook

Set oApp_Excel = CreateObject("EXCEL.APPLICATION")
Set oBook = oApp_Excel.Workbooks.Add

oBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(5, 3).Value = "masouud1"
oBook.SaveAs (path)
oBook.Close
oApp_Excel.Quit

Set oBook = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: `Workbooks.Add` creates a new workbook.

Comment: @MichaelMurphy Yes, but I don't know how to update my file.

Comment: I would try `Workbooks.Open`. [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open)

Comment: `Set oBook = oApp_Excel.Workbooks.Open(path)`. Supposing that the file already exists. Of course, `oBook.SaveAs (path)` will disappear and  `oBook.Close True` will close it after saving...